# Ext Js store joining filters

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to get records which have a specific word, but this word can be in any field.

For example:

```
 { firstName: 'Ed',         lastName: 'Spencer'},
 { firstName: 'Spencer',    lastName: 'Ed'}
```

If the records are like these above, then when I search Spencer, both of the records should be returned. Ext js applies filter over filter. Is there a way to apply store filters independently.

Comment: Have you tried `filterBy` (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-filterBy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
store.filterBy(function(rec, id) {
  if (YOUR CONDITION CHECK ON REC)
    return true; //the record will be shown
  else
    return false; //the record will be filtered out
});
```